# How can I update the message inside the data-confirmation attribute using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a polymorphic association with Resources & Flags in my rails app. Each Resource can be Flagged by a user.

On the Resource Edit Page, an Admin can delete multiple flags associated with each Resource via Jquery. (This works fine)

I am then trying to display the total number of flags remaining in an alert message using the data-confirmation attribute before a user updates a Resource.

**For Example:**

```
<%= f.submit "Update Resource", data: { confirm: "Reminder: You have #{@flaggable.flags.count} flag alerts remaining." } %>
```

For some reason, my jquery updates the entire div button VS the variable inside the data-confirmation attribute.

**How can I directly target the variable inside the data-confirmation attribute using Jquery?**

**Models**

```
class Resource 
  belongs_to :district
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable, :dependent => :destroy  
end 

class Flag 
  belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Resource Controller**

```
#edit page
def edit
  @district = District.find_by_abbreviation(params[:district_id])
  @resource = @district.resources.find(params[:id])   
  @flaggable = @resource
  @flags = @flaggable.flags.all 
end
```

**Views**

edit.html.erb - Resource Edit Page

```
###Renders all flags & allows a user to delete flags via Javascript.
<div id="flags">
  <%= render :partial => "flags/flag", :collection => @flags %>
</div>

###Resource Form
<div>
  <%= simple_form_for ([@district, @district_resource]) do |f| %>

    <div id="counter>

      ###How can I directly target the variable inside my alert message/data-confirm?
      <%= f.submit "Update Resource", data: { confirm: "Reminder: You have #{@flaggable.flags.count} flag alerts remaining." } %>

    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

_flag.html.erb (partial)

```
<div id="<%= dom_id(flag) %>" class="flag">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">
        <%= link_to '&times;'.html_safe, [@flaggable, flag], method: :delete,  remote: true  %>
      </span>
    </button>

    <b>Flag Alert: </b> <%= flag.message %>

</div>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
###This works and removes flags
$('#flags #<%= dom_id(@flag) %>').remove();

###This doesn't update the actual data-confirm attribute message
newFlagCount = $('#flags .flag').size();
$("#counter input[data-confirm]").data("Reminder: You have #{@flaggable.flags.count} flag alerts remaining.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined the answer below to solve the problem. Thanks everyone.

```
newFlagCount = $('#flags .flag').length;
var data = { confirm: "Reminder: You have " + newFlagCount + " flag alerts remaining." }
$("#counter input[data-confirm]").data('confirm', data.confirm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, `$("#counter")` is selecting the `<div id="counter">` div and `.html()` is changing the entire div content. So, your code is doing exactly what you are asking it to do. You should target the `submit` button inside your "counter" div and change the `data-confirm` attribute's text.

```
$("#counter input[data-confirm]").data("Reminder: You have #{@flaggable.flags.count} flag alerts remaining.");
```

Please note, that if you are changing the number of flags using javascript, the variable in the text will be the original value (`@flaggable.flags.count`). You would need to regex the digit in your attribute text and change it using javascript.

Comment: Don't need to change the code in your view if that's all you want. However, if you are changing the flags count using Javascript, that value in `data-confirm` text would not change. Assume when the page loads you have 5 flags and the confirmation message will say you have 5 flags. Then you allowed user to delete one of the flags and sent an ajax request to the server saying remove this flag. When a user clicks on the button again, confirmation message would still say you have 5 flags instead of 4.

Comment: If you haven't worked with regex yet, then simply replace the entire string after you delete a flag with javascript: `$("#counter input[data-confirm]").data("Reminder: You have " + newFlagCount + " flag alerts remaining.");`. Having said that, you only need to do this if your are doing any manipulation of flags in front end.

Comment: I take it that I have to set the variable newFlagCount somewhere right?

Comment: Yes, you can count number of flags using jQuery code like this: `newFlagCount = $('#flags li').size()`. Change the selector there. I am assuming your flags are in `li` tags.

Comment: You can change the selector to `newFlagCount = $('#flags div[id]').size()`. But I would suggest adding a class to your `<div id="<%= dom_id(flag) %>" class="flag">` and make the above selector more robust `newFlagCount = $('#flags .flag').size()`.

Answer (score 2):

put your JSON into a variable, then assign it into the element attribute:

```
var data = { confirm: "Reminder: You have #{@flaggable.flags.count} flag alerts remaining." }
$("#counter input").attr("data-confirm",data.confirm);
```